# How to optimize this in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, time-complexity

I want to find the number of pairs a large number. If i give number n and ask to determine, number of pairs such that

- `S(x) < S(y) where S(k) denotes the sum of digits of integer k.`
- `0 <= x < y <= n`

and constratints is `i <= n <= 10^250`

For example, let's say the number is `3` so valid pairs will be (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3) so it counts to 6. Hence the answer. For this I had written code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
from itertools import permutations

def sumofelement(n):
    sum = 0
    while(n>0):
        temp = n%10
        sum = sum + temp
        n = n//10
    return sum

def validpair(x):
    x, y = x
    if sumofelement(x) < sumofelement(y):
        return True

def countPairs(n):
    z = [x for x in range(n+1)]
    permuation = permutations(z, 2)
    count = 0
    for i in permuation:
        print(i, validpair(i))
        if validpair(i):
            count += 1
    return count%(1000000007)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input())
    result = countPairs(n)
    print(result)
```

But problem arises when the number is vary large, lets say 10^250. How can i optimize, I tried to search but not able to find any efficient solution.

Comment: There is a [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), no need for a proceedure.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question.

Comment: Hey! @thanasisp, still inputting `67535` takes lot's of time

Comment: @VaibhavSingh This is a dynamic programming problem.

Comment: Could you provide a more precise mathematical definition of what you call "the number of pairs [of] a large number"? I guess x and y are such a pair, and S is a function, but AFAIK the large number is nowhere to be found in your definition.

Comment: @AristideI I edited the description :)

Comment: It looks to me as if you do not implement the x < y constraint. And, consequently, neither do I or DSM or thanasisp.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Thanks. It's perfectly clear now.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answer does not consider the constraint `(x<y)` that was added later to question. And does not accept any huge input like `10^250`. It is suggestion to improve OP's code as requested.

---

It seems not necessary to actually generate the pairs. That means not to store and manipulate elements like `(1000, 900)` but directly their sum of digits: `(1,9)`

So you could make this modification to your existing function:

```
def countPairs(n):
    z = [sumofelement(x) for x in range(n+1)]
    p = permutations(z, 2)
    count = 0
    for x,y in p:
        if (x<y):
            count += 1
    return count%(1000000007)
```

**testing** for n=2K

```
> time python3 test.py #old
1891992

real    0m15.967s
user    0m15.876s
sys     0m0.049s
> time python3 test2.py #new
1891992

real    0m0.767s
user    0m0.739s
sys     0m0.022s
```

for n=5K

```
11838575

real    1m32.159s
user    1m30.381s
sys     0m0.444s

11838575

real    0m4.280s
user    0m4.258s
sys     0m0.012s
```

although it is 95% faster, it seems going O(n^2)

---

**So here is a different approach:**

```
from collections import Counter

def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s

def count_pairs(n):
    z = [sum_digits(x) for x in range(n+1)]
    c = Counter(z)
    final = sorted(c.items(), reverse=True)
    print(final)

    count = 0
    older = 0
    for k,v in final:
        count += older * v
        older += v
    return count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input())
    print(count_pairs(n))
```

we create a dict `{ sum_of_digits: occurences }` and we
make it a reversed list. For examle for `n=10` this would be

```
[(9, 1), (8, 1), (7, 1), (6, 1), (5, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1)]
```

As we go through it, at any node, the occurences multiplied to the sum of the previous nodes is the contribution of any numbers having this sum of digits to the total count. It is probably O(n). Counter size is tiny compared to our actual data.

**testing** with N=2K

```
[(28, 1), (27, 4), (26, 9), (25, 16), (24, 25), (23, 36), (22, 49), (21, 64), (20, 81), (19, 100), (18, 118), (17, 132), (16, 142), (15, 148), (14, 150), (13, 148), (12, 142), (11, 132), (10, 118), (9, 100), (8, 81), (7, 64), (6, 49), (5, 36), (4, 25), (3, 16), (2, 10), (1, 4), (0, 1)]
1891992

real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.014s
```

with N=67535

```
[(41, 1), (40, 5), (39, 16), (38, 39), (37, 80), (36, 146), (35, 245), (34, 384), (33, 570), (32, 809), (31, 1103), (30, 1449), (29, 1839), (28, 2259), (27, 2692), (26, 3117), (25, 3510), (24, 3851), (23, 4119), (22, 4296), (21, 4370), (20, 4336), (19, 4198), (18, 3965), (17, 3652), (16, 3281), (15, 2873), (14, 2449), (13, 2030), (12, 1634), (11, 1275), (10, 962), (9, 700), (8, 490), (7, 329), (6, 210), (5, 126), (4, 70), (3, 35), (2, 15), (1, 5), (0, 1)]
2174358217

real    0m0.278s
user    0m0.264s
sys     0m0.014s
```

Comment: No, for n=4 i have 10 pairs (4+3+2+1) = 10 pairs

Comment: It is not a normal series as by the formula mentioned above it will print 55, but the actual answer is 54, since(1,10) fails the condition. Look up the link to see the actual output of the code.
https://paste2.org/UBWx7vP0

Comment: for `n = 1000` my program took `13.6 sec` and your program took `0.55 sec`

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is the number of valid pairs, not the list of all valid pairs. You can compute this number by simple combinatorics and don't need to examine all possibilities.

For `n=3`, the number of pairs will be the number of pairs for `n=2` + the number of pairs in format `(x,3)`. The x can be in range `<0,n-1>` and that contains `n` elements.

The code can use recursion or cycle or formula, all of these codes should computer the same number, formula is obviously fastest.

```
def countPairs(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1 # pair (0,1)
    return countPairs(n-1) + n

def countPairs(n):
    ret = 0
    for x in xrange(1,n):
        ret+=x
    return ret

def countPairs(n):
    return n*(n-1)/2
```

Comment: This code will not work for 10^250, Python will greet with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: Added more effective implementation.

Comment: Read my comment to chepner.  The OP's countPairs function does not simply return the nth triangular number.

Comment: I had edited the description of problem. Please see as this is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

Let us - for a moment - ignore the second constraint x < y.

Then one strategy would be lumping together all numbers with the same sum of digits. For example, if your *n* is `10^250`, say, then the s.o.d. `1000` will occur exactly `1983017386182586348981409609496904425087072829264027113757253089553808835917213113938681936684409793628116446312878275672807319027255318921532869897133614537254127444640190990014430819413778762187558412950294708704055125267388491053875845430856889` times, while the s.o.d. `10` would occur `313933899756954150` times. So these two s.o.d.s together would give rise to the product of these numbers, i.e. `622536381330141298432969991820256911356499404510841221727177771404498196898219200726905190334516036530761185604472351714146659153338691825580165670694714765688631611013643183449188160088364429780094383087473530152672586062700335444189441183499432858425871184639350` pairs.

Or with slightly less megalomaniac numbers: n = 88, s.o.d.1 = 10, s.o.d.2 = 7 we get 8 and 8, hence 64 pairs.

The code below implements this strategy (function `nonsod`) using a simple recurrence relation going digit by digit. As there is a lot of redundant branching a cache is used.

The full count for *n* = `10^250` (still without enforcing x < y) is `49689518924223997098471223543364330459595831386684873270186194285660874002514005047966357557084650317768560146609913273315351520002512374912739761203458271777707529815027881619901050952541693486379889157466211100495006800815751752605470841565728511141845695222712435837491694221722360852940495211481721723206152092725455942611410225513504242173241811867522974465909681478041570056834016566434386955417360661126555266582980778790541324964301380703686112669669641207272764740986099727604245250714092580` and takes just a couple of seconds to compute.

Now let us bring back constraint two: x < y

We can use the unconstrained code by conditioning on the leftmost digit of x and y respectively. If they are the same, we can chop them off and use recurrencee. Otherwise, the one belonging to x must be smaller. After chopping both of we are essentially back at the one constraint problem. Only an additional 'grace' parameter is required. For example if the first digit of x was smaller than that of y by three then the remaining s.o.d.s of x may be up to two larger than that of y.

This algo gives the expected result to 67535, and 10^250 is still just about doable (2 min on my fairly modest laptop). Result: `25984328769282898156215987070093760297836281753626742070663593024918781683928674045441700800803359016753562494186043552665812224996953995704125243157891603184533274543105499314528302202972742702392476556566583829840036706378670333595223855845665062500914398291514442277659839377773164451943550566697849130769244805996419427202677753063819693113304304818586290078490380143872959635951851910822582661516954316275598690668540412688085631222123413887008350968291853549698946413333342843654709903250347001`

```
import itertools as it

_cache_a = {}
_cache_b = {}
_max_k = 300*9 + 1 # good for up to 300 digits

def maxsod(n):
    # find largest posssible sum of digits
    return (len(n) - 1) * 9 + int(n[0]) + all(d == '9' for d in n[1:])

def nonsod_str(n, k):
    # first anchor the recurrence and deal with some special cases
    if k < 0:
        return 0
    elif k == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == '0':
        return 0
    elif len(n) == 1:
        return int(k <= int(n))
    max_k_n = maxsod(n)
    if k >= max_k_n:
        return 0
    max_k_n = min(_max_k, max_k_n)
    _cache_n = _cache_a.setdefault(int(n), max_k_n * [-1])
    if _cache_n[k] < 0: # a miss
        # remove leftmost digit and any zeros directly following
        lead = int(n[0])
        for j, d in enumerate(n[1:], 1):
            if d != '0':
                break
        next_n = n[j:]
        nines = (len(n) - 1) * '9'
        _cache_n[k] = sum(nonsod_str(nines, k-j) for j in range(lead)) \
            + nonsod_str(next_n, k-lead)
    return _cache_n[k]

def nonsod(n, k):
    "number of numbers between 0 and n incl whose sum of digits equals k"
    assert k < _max_k
    return nonsod_str(str(n),  k)

def count(n):
    sods = [nonsod(n, k) for k in range(maxsod(str(n)))]
    sum_ = sum(sods)
    return (sum_*sum_ - sum(s*s for s in sods)) // 2

def mixed(n, m, grace):
    nsods = [nonsod(n, k) for k in range(maxsod(str(n)))]
    msods = ([nonsod(m, k) for k in range(maxsod(str(m)))]
             if n != m else nsods.copy())
    ps = it.accumulate(msods)
    if len(msods)-grace < len(nsods):
        delta = len(nsods) - len(msods) + grace
        nsods[-1-delta:] = [sum(nsods[-1-delta:])]
    return sum(x*y for x, y in zip(it.islice(ps, grace, None), nsods))

def two_constr(n):
    if (n<10):
        return (n * (n+1)) // 2
    if not n in _cache_b:
        n_str = str(n)
        lead = int(n_str[0])
        next_n = int(n_str[1:])
        nines = 10**(len(n_str)-1) - 1
        # first digit equal
        fde = two_constr(next_n) + lead * two_constr(nines)
        # first digit different, larger one at max
        fddlm = sum(mixed(next_n, nines, grace) for grace in range(lead))
        # first digit different, both below max
        fddbbm = sum((lead-1-grace) * mixed(nines, nines, grace)
                     for grace in range(lead-1))
        _cache_b[n] = fde + fddlm + fddbbm
    return _cache_b[n]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's failing for `67535`.
Output from your program: `174358203`
Expected output: `358739816`
i used `print(count(67535)%1000000007)`

Comment: Looking into it. My code appears to systematically fail for numbers ending with `9`. But, encouragingly, it gets > 90% of the inputs right (I checked everything up to 1000). How long does 67535 take with your code?

Comment: Lot's of time, Have to wait for very long time still i am not able to see the output of this

Comment: Ok, I fixed the trailing `9`s. Our programs now agree on the first `1000` ints. Sadly, the output for `67535` is unchanged. Btw, if it's not from your prog where does the number come from? Are there any other (ideally, smaller) expected results and does your prog get them right?

Comment: You had done a lot of optimization, but still answer is in correcct :'). If i could find, i will add it here

Comment: Nope, My progam take hell lot of time and didn't produce the output :(

Comment: My own approach -- which also matches countPairs for the first 1000 -- agrees with Paul's 10^250 and 67535 answers.  I reran 67535 using a different brute force approach and got the same result.  I'm currently 48/67 of the way through powering through on countPairs, but I'd be quite surprised if it disagreed.  I think we'd need to see a link to the actual puzzle itself, to see if maybe we're misinterpreting the question, because I'm running out of possible mistakes.

Comment: Okay, I just finished the 67535 count using three different approaches (countPairs, mine, and a faster brute) and they all give the same result as Paul's.  So either the question is wrong or 358739816 is.

Comment: @DSM Original question which i am solving https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/morgan-stanley-codeathon-2017/challenges/dreamplay-and-clubbing

Comment: @VaibhavSingh: Thanks.  Notice that the full question requires x < y, not merely S(x) < S(y) -- permutations(seq, 2) will generate values where `x > y` as well, so we're overcounting.

Comment: Not sure my algo can survive this. How about your's @DSM?

Comment: @PaulPanzer: originally I thought no, because I threw the ordering information away, but I have an idea now..

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Please check out the updated code. It does give the right answer to 67535 and it scales up to 10^250 - just...

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks a lot, but still i am getting wrong output at `67535`, I am getting `358739816` instead of `358739816`

Comment: @VaibhavSingh _I am getting 358739816 instead of 358739816_ ??? Those look pretty identical to me

Comment: @PaulPanzer I am sorry, I mean to say I am getting `174358203` instead of  `358739816`

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Ah, you are probably still using `count`? The relevant function is the one at the very bottom: `two_constr`. Sorry, should have mentioned that, I suppose.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Your program able to pass 7 test case out of 24. Rest gettting timeout. I am now thinking of dynamic programming approach, the only way we can get rid of timeout :)
Still learning, so it will take time for me to update the question with answer

Comment: @VaibhavSingh "the only way we can get rid of timeout". Why would that be? There are a couple of possible optimisations for this algorithm. For example: replace recurrence by loops. Better reuse computations made in `mixed` etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158877/discussion-between-vaibhav-singh-and-paul-panzer).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this (non optimized) algorithm should match the new formulation of the definition:

```
def digital_sum(n):
    return sum(int(c) for c in str(n))

def count(n):
    return sum(digital_sum(x) < digital_sum(y) for x in range(n) for y in range(x+1, n+1))

for n in range(1, 20):
    print(count(n), end=",")
```

It prints:

```
1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,46,49,54,61,70,81,94,109,126,145,
```

which is indeed unknown from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C3%2C6%2C10%2C15%2C21%2C28%2C36%2C45%2C46&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

---

Original post:

Judging by its output, your function seems to match [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A033442). A concise implementation should be:

```
def count(n):
    return sum(9 * i // 10 for i in range(n + 1))
```

Note that it's still to slow for `10^250`. Just my two cents.

Comment: 181 != 180, unfortunately.

Comment: OEIS gives 0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 54, 64, 75, 87, 100, 114, 129, 145, 162, 180... You mean that the OP sequence first differs on 180? Very unfortunate, indeed.

Comment: Now that we've seen the original question, I can confirm that A033442 is not the appropriate sequence.

Comment: @dsm Yes, and if my new program is correct, no OEIS sequence matches the desired output.